# how can i use "|find" in robot frame work

Tags: robotframework, command-prompt

I want to know the status of the virtual machine
In Command Prompt by executing the below command

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>vboxmanage showvminfo Linux |find "State:"
```

I got output as

```
=>State:                       running (since 2020-09-30T06:00:01.824000000)
```

the same thing when I tried in robot framework(RIDE)

```
#${result}=    Run process    C:\\Program Files\\Oracle\\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage    showvminfo    Linux    |find    "State:"
```

I am getting error as -

> Syntax error: Invalid parameter '|find'

Can someone help how to use `|find` in robot framework.

Comment: What happens if you do `|find` --> `|    find`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piping eg, using `|` character is shell feature. If you want to run shell commands or using features from it, you need to tell `Run Process` to run it inside a shell by adding `shell=yes` to your `Run Process` keyword.

This is documented in https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Process%20configuration and a section below it called **Running processes in shell**